# How to change src of application/pdf using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, pdf

I have an embeded code like this

```
<embed id="1000" style="display: ;" width="850" height="1100" src="/new_folder/hi.pdf"       type="application/pdf">
</embed>
```

and i have this code

```
<a onfocus="OnLink(this)" href="javascript:switch('1000','/new_folder/bye.pdf');" onmousedown="return VerifyHref this,event,'{$XmlDefinition/List/@DefaultItemOpen}','{$thisNode/@HTML_x0020_File_x0020_Type.File_x00    20_Type.mapcon}','{$thisNode/@serverurl.progid}')" >
<xsl:value-of select="$thisNode/@FileLeafRef.Name" />
</a>
```

and I have this function

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function switch(id,dirToPDF) { 
    $('1000').attr('data','dirToPDF'); 

} 
</script>
```

So when I click on the link, it should call switch, and change the pdf thats displayed (which is hi.pdf) to bye.pdf, but it's not working.

Can anyone help me with this?

---

### EDIT:

Ok so I changed it to

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
  function switchFunc(id, dirToPDF) {  
    $(id).attr('data', dirToPDF); 
  } 
</script> 


<a onfocus="OnLink(this)" href="javascript:switchFunc('pdf_d','/new_folder/bye.pdf');" onmousedown="return VerifyHref(this,event,'{$XmlDefinition/List/@DefaultItemOpen}','{$thisNode/@HTML_x0020_File_x0020_Type.File_x0020_Type.mapcon}','{$thisNode/@serverurl.progid}')" >
  <xsl:value-of select="$thisNode/@FileLeafRef.Name" />
</a>  


<embed id="pdf_d" style="display: ;" width="850" height="1100" src="/new_folder/hi.pdf" type="application/pdf">
</embed>
```

and it's still not working...

Comment: `'switch'` is keyword , you can't use that word to declare function and/or variable.

Comment: Shouldn't you put a '#' before the 1000, like this: $('#1000').attr('data','dirToPDF');

Comment: *Always* have the JavaScript error console visible when working on web page development.

Comment: And shouldn't that be `$('#1000')`? Also, `1000` is not a valid `id`. An id should be "any alphanumeric string (plus underscore) that **begins with a letter**".

Comment: Not to mention, you cannot start the `id` attribute with a number.

Comment: The "mousedown" handler should just be a "click" handler, and it should be combined with the code currently in the "href" value.  Also, the mousedown handler is *also* syntactically incorrect.

Comment: @TRiG the HTML5 specification does not require anything from an "id" value other than that it be non-empty and contain no space characters.

Answer (score 1):

Let me review:

- As @user1113426 said, you call a custom-defined 'switch' function to switch attributes-- however, `switch` is a reserved function, and I don't think you can overwrite it.
- As I said (then deleted) and @michaeldcooney said, you need to put a '#' sign before 1000;  Turning `$('1000')` to `$('#1000')`.
- As @NickBeranek said, you can't have an id field be completely numeric-- so `1000` won't work anyways. (Try the name of the doc-- `NewDocPdf`)
- Finally, the element attribute you are changing (`data`) is not the correct element to change.  You want to change `src`, as that is the one that chooses what document is loaded.

Related: *You have both an 'onmousedown' event AND an action when the link is clicked.*  They might cause interference, so it may be easier to do this..

**The Doc Window:**

```
<embed id="PDFDisplay" style="display: ;" width="850" height="1100" src="/new_folder/hi.pdf" type="application/pdf">
</embed>
```

**Links to Change:**

```
<a class="altDoc" href="javascript:return void;" whichDoc="/new_folder/bye.pdf" >
<xsl:value-of select="$thisNode/@FileLeafRef.Name" />
</a>
```

Next:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    switchFunc = function (jQueryObject) {
        console.log(jQueryObject);
        $('#PDFDisplay').attr('src',jQueryObject.attr('whichDoc') );
    }
    $('.altDoc').hover( function () { OnLink(this); } );
    $('.altDoc').click( function (event) {
        console.log("this");
        switchFunc(this);
        return VerifyHref(this,event,'{$XmlDefinition/List/@DefaultItemOpen}','{$thisNode/@HTML_x0020_File_x0020_Type.File_x00 20_Type.mapcon}','{$thisNode/@serverurl.progid}');
    } );
</script>
```

Let me know how the above works and I can provide any other alterations.

**EDIT**:
Looks like I forgot a few )s, ;s, etc.  Also, I kept a bad " and forgot an opening parenthesis after VerifyHref.

**EDIT THE SECOND**:

**You ever consider writing a bunch of  tags which have '`target="iFrameNameAttribute"`' ?**
You can have links specifically target an `iframe`, and you can have the iFrame content set to the embedded PDF.  Whenever you click on a link that targets the iFrame, it can change the content.

Comment: Numeric "id" values work fine in modern browsers, and the HTML5 spec does not place such restrictions on "id". Old versions of IE might not like them however.

Comment: just tried it, and same thing is happening like my previous script, the same original pdf still shows...

Comment: tried it again, and same result, also where are you calling the 'switchFunc' function?

Comment: Sorry-- i'm using jQuery pretty extensively.  Look at the `<script>` block.  I have two functions for any `<a>` tag with `class="altDoc"`:  I have a `hover` function (which calls `OnLink`), and I have a click function which calls `switchFunc(this)` and then returns the result of `VerifyHref`.    ------ **SOMETHING TO NOTE**: I added an attribute to the `<a>` tags called `whichDoc`.  The `switchFunc(this)` function now uses that to know what to change the PDF `src` to.  (See the revised `<a>` tag above.)

Comment: In your response to the other answer, you ask "How do I reload the tag?"   Two suggestions:  1. Try a .hide() and .show().  This might trigger a re-draw.  2.  Try Deleting the element and re-adding it to the page using jQuery. `$('embed').remove().append($('<embed>').attr({'src':'/new/file.pdf','height':'100px','width','200px','etc':'etc'});` .. that last line is a guess and requires you to edit it a bit. :(

Answer (score 0):

Please modify your script as follows and pass in the id parameter:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function switchFunc(id, dirToPDF) { 
    $('#' + id).attr('data', dirToPDF);
  }
</script>
```

`switch` is a reserved name in JS. Also, `1000` is not a valid id. ID's cannot start with a number.

Comment: You still need to prepend a "#" to the "id" value. Numeric "id" values [work fine](http://jsfiddle.net/3mGbN/) in modern browsers, though older versions of IE might have issues.

Comment: Modified answer to include the pound sign.

Comment: I figured out that, the src is changing, but I need to somehow refresh/reload the embed tag, does anyone know how?